# is it possible to set a foreign key column that can be related to more than a table

Tags: sql, laravel

I have a ticket booking system for a traveling company. I have a ticket table, bus table, plane table, and steamship table. The tickets table has a `transport_id` column that can have a relation with any of these tables. Is this possible in SQL or is there a good trick to do it with laravel?

I thought about making another column called, say, `type` that has a table name and get the rows I need with an eloquent like this:

```
public function transports()
{
   $transport = DB::table($this->type)->where('id', $this->transport_id)->get();
   return DB::table('tickets')->where('id', $transport->id)->first();
}

// in transport Models
public function tickets()
{
   return Ticket::where("type", "TABLE_NAME")->all();
}
```

This way seems a little hacky. I just want to know if there's a function or something to do this in a better way.

Comment: laravel has this feature in its polymorphic relationships ... their are blueprint methods for your schema to create the id and type column and you can define these relationships on the models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Laravel's Eloquent [one-to-many polymorphic relation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations):

If you follow the [table structure](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-table-structure) you can query like:

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the parent transport model (buss, plane, etc).
     */
    public function ticketable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
 
class Plane extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the plane's tickets.
     */
    public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Ticket::class, 'ticketable');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! can I use `new $plane->getMorphClass()` ?  I know I can use `$plane->tickets()->create([...])`

Comment: welcome! No, but you can use: `$ticket = new Ticket([...]); $plane->comments()->save($ticket);`

Comment: oh thanks! that's what I was looking for. You're underrated, you must've more than 50k reputation